# Importing numpy and pandas in Jupyter Notebook on Windows 10 ARM

Tags: windows, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

When I install the 32-bit Anaconda on my Surface Pro X and try to run import numpy and pandas within the Jupyter notebook I get this error.

I tried updating the packages using conda update numpy.

```
C:\Users\mechm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\getlimits.py:174: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in exp2
  eps=exp2(ld(-112)),
C:\Users\mechm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\getlimits.py:53: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log10
  self.precision = int(-log10(self.eps))
C:\Users\mechm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\getlimits.py:54: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in power
  self.resolution = float_to_float(float_conv(10) ** (-self.precision))
C:\Users\mechm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\getlimits.py:186: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in exp2
  epsneg_f80 = exp2(ld(-64))
C:\Users\mechm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\getlimits.py:187: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in exp2
  tiny_f80 = exp2(ld(-16382))
C:\Users\mechm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\getlimits.py:201: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in exp2
  eps=exp2(ld(-63)),
C:\Users\mechm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\getlimits.py:214: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in nextafter
  if hasattr(umath, 'nextafter')  # Missing on some platforms?
C:\Users\mechm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\getlimits.py:226: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in exp2
  eps=exp2(ld(-105)),
C:\Users\mechm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\getlimits.py:227: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in exp2
  epsneg= exp2(ld(-106)),
C:\Users\mechm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\getlimits.py:229: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in exp2
  tiny=exp2(ld(-1022)))
C:\Users\mechm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:210: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in subtract
  if not abs(x.dot(x) - 2.0) < 1e-5:
C:\Users\mechm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:210: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in absolute
  if not abs(x.dot(x) - 2.0) < 1e-5:
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a possible workaround, I ran this. No idea why it works.

```
import sys
!conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} numpy
```

Comment: Looks like the packages actually work, that error is unnecessary then. I just suppressed the error.